# Emploi de "animal politique"

Tags: grec, politique

Vu (entre autres sources) ici

https://www.courrierinternational.com/article/vu-de-letranger-jacques-chirac-la-mort-dun-animal-politique

> L’ancien président de la République est décédé ce jeudi 26 septembre
>   2019. La presse étrangère rend hommage à cet “animal politique...”

Ici

https://la-philosophie.com/homme-animal-politique-aristote

l'origine de cette expression est expliquée exhaustivement. [En bref] C’est Aristote qui, dans La Politique, le premier a qualifié l’homme de “Zoon Politikon” (homme animal politique).

L'article ici

https://www.persee.fr/doc/bude_0004-5527_1928_num_18_1_4495

explique le sens selon Aristote.

Peut-on utiliser cette expression couramment ? L'emploi de cette expression signifie-t-il qu'un journal ou un site s'adresse à un public mieux éduqué et cultivé ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sans problème, si cela désigne une personne qui déploie une énergie et une intelligence politique hors norme.

C’est une expression "tout public".

Comment: +1 même si j'aurais préféré (rapport à l'animalité) un ***sens** politique* voire un *sens inné de la politique* à l'*intelligence* politique.

Answer (score 4):

En fait « animal politique » a deux sens différents.

Quand Aristote parle d'« animal politique » (enfin, quand il utilise une expression qu'on traduit comme cela en français), il signifie que la biologie de l'être humain le conduit à se comporter d'une manière qui fait intervenir la politique. Cela n'a pas vraiment de sens de dire qu'une personne en particulier est un animal politique : c'est le cas de tout être humain (à un degré plus ou moins élevé).

Ici, le mot *animal* a un sens différent : en langue familière, il désigne quelqu'un pour lequel on a une certaine admiration, ou au contraire par antiphrase quelqu'un pour lequel on a un certain dédain. Avec un adjectif, cela signifie que l'admiration ou le dédain est dû à cette qualité. Dire de quelqu'un que c'est un « animal politique », cela signifie qu'on considère qu'il est doué pour la politique (que l'on trouve cela bien ou mal). Voir les sens [C du *Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/animal). Plus précisément, c'est quelqu'un pour qui la politique est naturelle : tellement naturelle qu'il n'a pas besoin d'appliquer une intelligence humaine (censée être supérieure à une éventuelle intelligence animale) pour faire de la politique. La politique est pour lui un instinct. On utilise aussi le mot *bête* dans ce sens (ou au moins, avec un sens voisin : les nuances peuvent être subtiles), surtout dans l'expression « [bête de scène](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%AAte_de_sc%C3%A8ne) ».

Il est probable que le journaliste qui a écrit cette phrase y voit un jeu de mot entre l'allusion à Aristote et le sens familier. En revanche, le Français moyen ne connaît certainement pas l'expression d'Aristote, et je ne suis pas sûr même que le lecteur moyen du *Courrier international* (qui est certainement plus cultivé que la moyenne) la connaisse. Pour ma part, je ne rattachais pas l'expression à Aristote, et je n'y vois que le sens « a un instinct pour la politique ».